# Problem with Khan Academy Challenge - Hovering over a button is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, hover, prototype

I'm working my way through the Khan Academy advanced JS and I've encountered what I feel should be a simple problem, but I've just gotten entirely stuck on it. I'm working on a memory tile game, trying to add some extra features.

I'm trying to change the stroke colour of an object when the mouse is over it - I've included this as a prototype in each 'tile' object and this check is performed during the **draw** function - so every frame.

The stroke colour does change as I wanted it to, but stops working once I 'flip up' a couple of the tiles and they flip back down, the hover effect stops working. It now works only when a single tile is flipped up.

I can't figure out why the 'face up' variable in the tile object would be affecting the hover check - I feel I'm missing something obvious but for the life of me can't see it.

I've looked at some similar projects and their button highlighting, they seem to do exactly the same thing as me.

**The Tile Object -**

```
var Tile = function(x, y, face) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = 70;
    this.face = face;
    this.isFaceUp = false;
    this.isMatch = false;    
};

Tile.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.hover();
    fill(214, 247, 202);
    strokeWeight(2);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size, 10);
    if (this.isFaceUp) {
        image(this.face, this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    } else {
        image(getImage("avatars/leaf-green"), this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    }
};

//Mouse Hover code - only works one time for some reason. After flipping back this stops working for some reason.
Tile.prototype.hover = function() {
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    if (this.isMouseInside()){
        stroke(7, 122, 44);
    }
};

Tile.prototype.isUnderMouse = function(x, y) {
    return x >= this.x && x <= this.x + this.size  &&
        y >= this.y && y <= this.y + this.size;
};

//check if mouse cursor is inside the tile
Tile.prototype.isMouseInside = function() {
    return mouseX > this.x &&
           mouseX < (this.x + this.size) &&
           mouseY > this.y &&
           mouseY < (this.y + this.size) &&
           this.isFaceUp === false;
};
```

**The Mouse Clicked Function - prewritten by KA**

```
mouseClicked = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        var tile = tiles[i];
        if (tile.isUnderMouse(mouseX, mouseY)) {
            if (flippedTiles.length < 2 && !tile.isFaceUp) {
                tile.isFaceUp = true;
                flippedTiles.push(tile);
                if (flippedTiles.length === 2) {
                    numTries++;
                    if (flippedTiles[0].face === flippedTiles[1].face) {
                        flippedTiles[0].isMatch = true;
                        flippedTiles[1].isMatch = true;
                        flippedTiles.length = 0;
                        numMatches++;
                    }
                    delayStartFC = frameCount;
                }
            } 
            loop();
        }
    }
};
```

**The Draw function - prewritten by KA**

```
draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    if (delayStartFC && (frameCount - delayStartFC) > 30) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
            var tile = tiles[i];
            if (!tile.isMatch) {
                tile.isFaceUp = false;
            }
        }
        flippedTiles = [];
        delayStartFC = null;
        noLoop();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        tiles[i].draw();
    }

    if (numMatches === tiles.length/2) {
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        textSize(20);
        text("You found them all in " + numTries + " tries!", 20, 375);
    }
};

noLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

It drove me nuts trying to work out a function for mouse over then it hit me, my solution to change the stroke weight on rollover. in the `Tile.prototype.draw` function add:

```
if (this.isUnderMouse(mouseX, mouseY)){
  strokeWeight(5);
}
else {
  strokeWeight(2);    
}
```